# Is it possible to store a typename?

Tags: c++

**Functor Disfunction:**

In c++, is there a way for an instance of a template class to be aware of its type? For instance, I have a class functor, which happens to utilize two typename template parameters. One for the return type of the function and one for the parameter type. I'd like a way to store both of these types, so that I can easily use the functor at a later time without passing in the types.

**Why:**

I have a thread pool class that I would like to store all of these functors in, and I'd like more than one type of function to be able to be handled. So I think it necessary to know the types of the function so I can call the function at a later time while storing it in a class that is not based on a template (except for the set_function/set_parameter method of course).

Comment: You might want to give us more information. Templates are a compile time construct, `void *` is more of a run time thing, at least in the sense that I think you're asking. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but wouldn't `typedef` be enough for you?

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity- this is why I shouldn't ask questions after midnight. As for the answer, it doesn't matter. I'm making a thread pool - and I was curious if a templated instance could be aware of its own type.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a typedef to the template type, something like:

```
template <typename T>
class X {
    typedef T value_type;
};
```

And then can reference that type like so:

```
void* p = /* some initialization to an X<int>::value_type */;
X<int>::value_type* x = static_cast<X<int>::value_type*>(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess what you're doing/what you want, it'd be something like this.  (This is a complete leap of faith at guessing what you *actually* want rather than what you *say* you want.)

```
class interface {
public: 
  virtual std::unique_ptr<interface> create() const =0; //virtual "constructor" 
  virtual bool is_same_type(const interface* ptr) const =0; //type comparison

  virtual void func() =0; //function
  virtual ~interface() {}
};

template<class T>
class instantiation : public interface
{
public: 
  virtual std::unique_ptr<interface> create() const
  { return std::unique_ptr<interface>(new instantiation()); }
  virtual bool is_same_type(const interface* ptr) const
  { return dynamic_cast<instantiation*>(ptr) != NULL; }

  virtual void func() {}
  virtual ~interface(){}
};
```

With this concept, you can make a container store `interface`s, and they "remember" their types enough to make new instances with the same template, and compare to see if they have the same template as another.

(Thanks to Xeo for translating phone texting to proper C++)

Comment: How do you write that much code on a phone? That sounds like a PITA.

Comment: @Johannes: It... *works*. The spelling correction is annoying though. Especially the automatic capital latter at the beginning of a new line. Mercifully, some phones allow you to disable that. | Added `const` to the `create` function, it doesn't need to change any instance data.

Comment: Yeah, it took me a good 20thing minutes, since every time I put two spaces it would "guess" the next word as "std::vector<char>" and "helpfully" insert that.  (Oh look, it guessed "thing" too!)